# iterating an array backwards in For loop condition to stop at 0 when using unsigned integers causing infinite loop

Tags: c, size-t

I have a loop that has to go from j to 0 (inclusively). My `j` variable is of type `size_t` which is usually unsigned.

My code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

#define SIZE 100

int main(){
    char str[SIZE];
    size_t i=0;
    size_t j;
    puts("Enter any string");
    scanf("%s",str);
    while(str[i]!='\0'){
        i++;
    }


    for(j=i-1;j>=0;j--){

        printf("%c",str[j]);
    }


    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

I get an infinite loop. If I remove the equality of zero it outputs the reverse of string without the first letter. so what's the problem here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`size_t` is an unsigned integer and it's never going to be less than `0`. So
the condition in `for` loop is always true:

```
for(j=i;j>=0;j--)
```

You can modify the condition to (a bit ugly though):

```
for(j=i; j-- > 0;){
   ...
}
```

Note that in your condition, you are printing the `\0` null byte too, which is a non-printable character. (since the `j` starts with a value equal to the string length). The above condition takes care of that too.

Also:

- you can use `strlen()`instead of looping over it yourself.
- Check the return value of `scanf()` if input reading wad successful.

Comment: Yes i have noticed that j should start form i-1 and i fixed thank you

Comment: Thank you my problem is solved with many solution and i know that i can use strlen()..But please can you explain to my why mu code is causing infinite loop??and why if i just replace size_t by int the output will be correct??what's the problem with size_t ??suppose that the loop comes to j=0 it should print the element zero and after that should be exit since the condition will be false so why it's entering in infinite loop??

Comment: `size_t`, an unsigned integer can't have a value less than 0. So if you do j-- when j was 0, then it will become SIZE_MAX (the maximum value size_t can hold). Let's say SIZE_MAX is 4294967295 then the loop would run from j -> 0 -> 4294967295 -> 0 -> and the cycle will go on. if you use `int`, it'll work as you expected. But `size_t` is the right type to use to find the length of the string.Hence, you get infinite loop. if you use `int`, it'll work as you expected. But `size_t` is the right type to use to find the length of the string.

Answer (score 9):

```
for(j=i; j>0; j--) {
    printf("%c", str[j-1]);
}
```

Would be another option.
For a beginner maybe easier to understand.
But the other answers would be better.

edit: i'd say the best would be `for(j=i; j-- > 0;)` by l3x.
decrementing j after checking if it is greater then 0.

Using a do{}while() loop would also work.

```
j = i;
do {
   j--;
   printf("%c", str[j]);
} while (j > 0);
```

Comment: This looks like a sheer example of ugly code with bizarre formatting.

Answer (score 6):

You could change `j` from `size_t` to `long` this makes sure all the data still fits and you can reach the `-1` value.

Another option is to end the for loop with the following statement:

```
for (j = i - 1;;--j)
{
    // code
    if (j == 0) break;
}
```

as a side-note: your first while loop does the same as the `strlen()` in `string.h`.

Comment: `j=i; do { ...; j--; } while(j != 0);` is probably more readable though.

Comment: ssize_t  is defined to be a signed  version of size_t.

Answer (score 5):

Down counting loops tend to end up a bit obscure and hard to read. Consider using this alternative instead:

```
const size_t max = i-1; // maximum value that j can have

for(j=0; j<=max; j++)
{
  ... str[max-j];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Unsigned integers will wrap in C. Any unsigned integer is always equal or larger than 0, in code: `uint >= 0`, is always true.

You can use a comparison with SIZE_MAX, since that is the largest value for type size_t. The code will iterate and print down to 0, as it should, then wrap to SIZE_MAX, and the loop will end. (This assumes the length of the string isn't SIZE_MAX.)

```
for(j=i; j < SIZE_MAX ;j--){

    printf("%c",str[j]);
}
```

Also note that your code prints the null character. So the starting index should be `j=i-1`, which works nicely with the wrapping behavior, since if the string's length is 0, the for loop will not print anything, because `i-1 == SIZE_MAX`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `j >= 0` is always `true` because `j` is `unsigned`.

When counting down to zero with an `unsigned`, I usually use postfix `--`:

```
while (j-- > 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unsigned value wraps around so when `j == 0` and the loop does `j--`, `j >= 0` is still true.

A basic and easy to read solution goes like this:

```
void reversePrint(char str[])
{
    size_t j = strlen(str);
    while (j-- > 0)
        printf("%c", str[j]);
}
```

Will print the string in reverse order : `olleH`.

Comment: Not the downvoter though, I think they didn't like the way you said *"...easy to read solution goes like..."* : `..while (j --> 0)...` which will make users [ask this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-name-of-the-operator-in-c) ; And secondly your superfulous use of `strlen` on the *string literal*, `str` whose size length is known at compile time.